# How to add Moderators to a Feed Group in getstream

Tags: getstream-io

We are building Feed Groups similar to Facebook Groups and we want admin and moderator functionalities to be implemented. How can we implement such functionality?

Presently, we thought of two ways,

1) Have a separate feed group `UnApprovedFeed` for unapproved posts and once the feed from `UnApprovedFeed` gets approved, it gets deleted from `UnApprovedFeed` and gets published to `Normal FeedGroup`,

2) Have an extra boolean object `Approved` to the activity, and filter based upon it, If approved the boolean is `true` else `false`.

Or is there any available abstraction for moderators already in Stream?

Comment: Hey @vanquishers how did you manage to create the group feed permission? Is that a feed where everyone can publish activity and everyone can read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both of your ideas will work, but the second option is what we've seen most frequently (and what we've done ourselves in a few projects our services team have done for customers). You can have your front end query that field and just not display.

Comment: How to display all unapproved posts to the moderator in the second option? The only way we can do that is to loop over all the posts and display them, then, in that case, looking at the complexity, it looks like the first option is better? what is the reason that your service team has adopted the second method over the first one, when you cannot guarantee the number of posts in every pagination? what if all the posts in a paginated query are unapproved, that may falsely signal the user that there are no activities left, or we may have to make a double API request sometimes to fill the page

Comment: please point me if I am wrong or if there are any tradeoffs where second option is better to use.

Comment: You can definitely do the first option - just be aware there will obviously be a delay. If the user is notified that there will be a delay, then that could work.